# Touch function does not work on Ubuntu with JDK1.8

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, java-8, touch-event

I'm working on a JavaFX 8 project on Ubuntu 18.04.2. While there is a problem with touch function.

In order to enable touch function I have a Launcher class:

```
package controller;

import com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
        //System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "none");


        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(MainApp.class, SplashPage.class, args);
    }
}
```

When touching the screen, the following sequence of mouse events is fired as expected:

MOUSE_PRESSED

MOUSE_RELEASED

MOUSE_CLICKED

But actually I get the follwing sequence of events:

MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET

MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET

The touchscreen drive I am using is eGalaxTouch Virtual Device for Touch, and it works well on other applications except Javafx.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

Force JavaFX to use gtk-2 by using the java parameter `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`